# Apt time between requests in python?

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests, google-crawlers

Using python request module(get function) I am scraping the links i.e. a crawler. I make multiple requests using the script. Since I was giving too many requests, Google intervened with CAPTCHA which was reset after sometime. I am using time module to put code to sleep for some time after each request to avoid it. I want to know what will be the apt time to put the script to sleep so that Google doesnt see it as invalid traffic ? 
(I am using a college proxy server)

Comment: Google uses multiple parameters to determine unusual traffic. They obviously aren't sharing what these parameters are, but I don't think request delay is most important. How about User-Agent, JS, referer? If you didn't touch these, it screams "I'm a bot".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I founded this sites very helpful for correct crawling: h

- https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-prevent-getting-blacklisted-while-scraping/
- https://webscraping.com/blog/How-to-crawl-websites-without-being-blocked/

Enjoy!